# Wiki software with image similarity search

Tags: wiki

Is there a wiki software with the following features:

- Search images which are similar to a given image
- Provide an automatic gallery of recently added images (and videos) sorted by time added/modified
- If you click on a picture on the search results or in the gallery, it links you to the corresponding page (or list of pages) including the image (or a similar mechanism).
- It should be easy to provide the image for similarity search with a smartphone
- It should be easy to push images or videos to the server from a smartphone or tablet (which you can tag immediately or later and include them in wiki pages later via a PC).
- The wiki should be free and open source

Additional "nice to have" features:

- Mathjax-support
- Some kind of cloning feature for offline use